# Member functions with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've recently started working with hooks and have a relatively simple question about "member functions". Previously, member functions worked like this in a react class:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = { toggle: false };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  // Member function
  toggle() {
    this.setState(toggle: !this.state.toggle); 
  }

  render() {
    <button onClick={this.toggle}>Toggle Me!</button>
  }
}
```

However, now with React Hooks, I'm not using `class` components, but still need a function to do stuff like this. Is it poor practice to do something like this? If so, what is the best practice here?

```
const App = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  // Kind of like a "member" function
  const toggleState = () => setToggle(!toggle); 

  return <button onClick={toggleState}>Toggle Me!</button>;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks good. It works for the absolute majority of cases, but if you want to create a function that gets memoized between renders you can use the `useCallback` hook so that e.g. the props sent to a `PureComponent` will be the same and doesn't cause unnecessary renders.

```js
const { useState, useCallback, PureComponent } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const toggleState = useCallback(() => setToggle(toggle => !toggle), []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{toggle ? 'On' : 'Off'}</div>
      <VeryExpensiveComponent onClick={toggleState} />
    </div>
  );
};

class VeryExpensiveComponent extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log("Rendered expensive component");
    return <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Toggle Me!</button>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: you could use useMemo instead of PureComponent.

Comment: @ArberSylejmani Sure, hence the "e.g." in my answer. There are more than one case when it's appropriate.

Comment: there are also case when re-rendering doesn’t create performance issues, such in the question, so the use of useCallback's optimization costs more than not having the optimization